# PySide QImage produces poor quality pixelated rendering on OS X

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

In a PySide application I'm developing, I've come across an extremely frustrating issue that I have spent days trying to solve. I subclassed `QLabel`and set a `QPixmap`, which can be scaled to any desired width while maintaining the aspect ratio. I understand that the `scaledToWidth` and `scaledToHeight` methods are bound to slightly distort the image but the distortion was not to the magnitude I expected. I've attempted both `SmoothTransformation` AND `FastTransformation`, the latter yielding more sharp and pixelated but less blurred and ugly. I've tried every acceptable image format and they all exhibit the same horrible rendering. Below is my `QLabel` subclass which holds the image:

```
class JXImageView(QLabel):

def __init__(self, parent, window, image, select_image, identifier, scaled_width=60, x=0, y=0):
    super(JXImageView, self).__init__(parent)
    self.move(x, y)
    pxm = QPixmap().fromImage(QImage(image))
    pxm = pxm.scaledToWidth(scaled_width, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
    self.setPixmap(pxm)
    self.setFixedSize(pxm.size())
```

What the image looks like with `SmoothTransformation`:

[image]

Here is the original Image:

[image]

Comment: What percentage are you scaling from the original image? Qt, like most image scaling, performs very poorly when the scaled size is significantly different than your original image size (say, greater than 3 to 1). For an object like that, you could look into vectorized graphics (PySide has partial support for SVG, which should be sufficient in your case, as this object can easily be re-created in SVG).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the graphics system to native.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('native')
```

This may improve the rendering but 'native' can be buggy on OSx. Better support is provided in Qt5 which is being included in pyside2 (under development).